# Why use "his" in association with the word "mankind"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, grammatical-gender, agreement, pronominal-agreement

The economist Keynes in a book wrote:

> The power to become habituated to **his** surroundings is a marked characteristic of mankind.

I would have used "its" instead but since English is not my mother-tongue and Keynes was probably a good writer I am sure I am the one being mistaken.

Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: or `one's` surroundings

Answer (score 14):

The use of 'his' refers to each 'member' of mankind. Mankind is generally referred to in this way, i.e. as a group of individual people, as opposed to a single, monolithic body, which would be suggested by using 'its'.

Comment: I think this answer goes to the point of the question, where several other answers have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

"his" (male pronoun) emphasises that it's a human.

"its" (neuter pronoun) would suggest a less human thing or entity.

Compare:

> Jeremy the baker got used to **his** surroundings

and

> Fido the dog got used to **its** surroundings

Comment: I think a lot of people would still use his or her for a dog. But it's hard to think of an inanimate example of something getting used to surroundings.

Comment: How about a ghost?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old conundrum. English has no proper neutral pronoun to either a male or female person. *It* is usually used to refer to inanimate or not-human things.

You could say:

> The power to become habituated to **one's** surroundings is a marked characteristic of mankind.

But the usage of *one* as a pronoun has come to sound a bit pretentious. I believe there is a shift occurring in english where *their* is being used in the singular and becoming acceptable.

> The power to become habituated to **their** surroundings is a marked characteristic of mankind.

Some would take it a step further.

> The power to become habituated to their surroundings is a marked characteristic of humans.

But that's somehow less poetic. *Humans* seems more clinical, and *mankind* more familial and grandiose somehow.

Comment: I don't think "one" makes a good substitute third-person pronoun. It's used instead of "you" in formal documents, i.e. it's a *second* person pronoun.

Comment: @Martha Actually, in British affected speech, it can also substitute for "I". I'm using it in the sense of "a person of the speaker's kind; such as the speaker himself or herself" see: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/one

Comment: Lest we forget, there is also *humankind*.

Answer (score -5):

In English, male pronouns are used for single persons of unknown gender. However, feminists and other groups find this fundamental grammar offensive, so they force awkward and incorrect phrasings like *one's* and the singular *their*.

Comment: This response does not answer the question "Why use 'his' in association with the word 'mankind'?"